# Mass insert of data with intermediate lookups using Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, json, database

I have a file that is several G in size and contains a JSON hash on each line.  The document itself is *not* a valid JSON document, however I have no control over the generation of this data so I cannot change it.

The JSON needs to be read, lookups need to be performed on certain "fields" in the JSON and then the result of these lookups needs to be inserted into a MySQL database.

At the moment, it is taking hours to process this file and I think that it is because I am inserting and commiting on each row instead of using executemany, however I'm struggling to work out how best to approach this because I need to do the lookups as part of the process and then insert into multiple tables.

The process is effectively as follows:

1) Iterate over the file, reading each line as we go

2) For each line, work out if it needs to be inserted into the database

3) If the line does need to be inserted into the database, look up foreign keys for various JSON fields and replace them with the FK id

4) Insert the "new" line into the database.

The issue comes at (3) as there are some cases where the FK id is *created* by an insert of a subset of the data.

In short, I need to do a mass insert of a nested data structure with various parts of the nested data needing to be inserted into different tables whilst maintaining referential integrity.

Thanks for all and any help,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1) filter out the lines you can ignore.
- 2) work out your table dependency graph and partition rows into multiple files by table.
- 3) insert all rows for tables without dependencies; optionally, cache these so you don't have to ask the DB what you just told it for lookups.
- N) use that cache + do any DB lookups required to insert rows that depend on rows inserted in step N-1.

Do all this as multiple processes so you can verify each stage. Use bulk inserts and consider disabling FK verification.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.  Hope things are well with you :)